# Amazon DynamoDb Local with Maven and Java8

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

i try to start a DynamoDb as embedded service. But when try to start it, i get the following error:

I create an example project at: https://github.com/marcelalburg/aws-dynamodb-local

if you run mvn spring-boot:run your get this exception:

Thanks a lot

Marcel

```
Initializing DynamoDB Local with the following configuration:
Port:   8000
InMemory:   true
DbPath: null
SharedDb:   false
shouldDelayTransientStatuses:   false
CorsParams: *

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dynamoDbConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: The request processing has failed because of an unknown error, exception or failure. (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 500; Error Code: InternalFailure; Request ID: 9cced04b-da87-48b0-b9e1-66a2fdb1f94f)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:687)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:967)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:956)
    at example.Application.main(Application.java:18)
Caused by: com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: The request processing has failed because of an unknown error, exception or failure. (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 500; Error Code: InternalFailure; Request ID: 9cced04b-da87-48b0-b9e1-66a2fdb1f94f)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1182)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:489)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:310)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.invoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:1776)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.listTables(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:1203)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.listTables(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:1216)
    at example.DynamoDbConfiguration.init(DynamoDbConfiguration.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:133)
    ... 17 more
```

``

Comment: I got the same issue, any updates??

Comment: I'm using something like this now: https://gist.github.com/thecarlhall/f4e8f425cb736938e1d2

Comment: finally I got the reason, my path to sqlite ( sqlite4java.library.path) libraries was wrong, actually it's really weird to get this error when pass is wrong, it's not clear and difficult to realise what's going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably due to Java Library Path issue, for me it started working after I added the below System Property in my IDE

```
-Djava.library.path=C:\Setups\sqlite4java-392
```

I had to download and extract the sqlite4java from this location - https://bitbucket.org/almworks/sqlite4java

I believe this can be set programmatically in the build system too. It would have been much better if Amazon DynamoDB had given more appropriate error.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this same error with the path to sqlite4.  Had a space in the path which got converted to %20 which caused these 2 lines to not work as planned.

```
val sqliteLibPath = getClass.getClassLoader.getResource("./lib").getPath
System.setProperty("sqlite4java.library.path", sqliteLibPath)
```